# addEventListner "change" not working for input elements

Tags: javascript, html

```
let title = document.querySelectorAll(".title");

title.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("", () => {
      console.log("hello")
    });
  });
```

this is my javascript part.

when I hover over the empty colons vs code shows 2 options "fullscreenerror" and "fullscreenerror" but they are both input elements. For some reason "change" is not working in there.

I am new to javascript and I have tried multiple things but none of those fixed the problem.
Please help.

Comment: May be [ask] can help you to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the event to you AddEventListner

Check this for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers

About your question here is a solution:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="title" />
```

JavaScript based on your try:

```
let title = document.querySelectorAll(".title");

title.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("change", () => {
      console.log("hello")
    });
  });
```